# Bash script with execute permissions won't run with double click

Tags: nautilus, bash

I have a bash script that has permission to execute, but when I double click it in nautilus it won't execute, instead it opens as text in `gedit`.

In properties it says open with: `gedit`, and that doesn't change when I click the `reset` button.

What do I have to do to make it execute? I'm running Ubuntu 13.04. I never had an issue like this one with 12.04 or with any other distribution in general.

**EDIT**
If I go in terminal and type: `./bashscriptname` it runs just fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Open Nautilus.
2. Go to **File** → **Preferences** (in Ubuntu 14.04, you might find it under **Edit** → **Preferences**).

   [image]
3. Go to the **Behavior** tab and click on **Run executable text files when they are opened**.

   [image]

   Or, choose **Ask each time** to be prompted every time you double click.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with Ubuntu, but on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, I had to go to the "Edit" menu to find "Preferences".

Comment: @Nick I've updated my answer to include that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this blog post [here](http://dfourtheye.blogspot.com/2013/06/Ubuntu-13-04-Execute-scripts-on-double-click.html),

Open file explorer `Files`. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and select `Preferences`. It should show something like this

[image]

In the `Behavior` tab, select `Ask each time` and close it. By default, it will be in `View executable text files when they are opened`. Now whenever you double click on a shell script, it will ask you what to do. If you want to straight away execute the script, select the first option `Run executable text files when they are opened`