# My bash script only opens editor, why doesn't it run?

Tags: bash, scripts, gnome-terminal, executable

I created a script to dd sdb to sdc on my older computer with Ubuntu 13. It ran when I clicked on it – asked if I wanted to run in terminal or edit it. On a newer computer, with Ubuntu 14, I created the same script on my desktop and made it executable, but when I click on it, the file simply opens in an editor with no opportunity to execute it.
So I copied the 'Simple Bash Example' script from "[How do I create a script file for terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223691/how-do-i-create-a-script-file-for-terminal-commands)" and made it executable. Same result; click on it and the file simply opens in an editor with no opportunity to execute it. 
(I have not tried reverting to Ubuntu 13.)  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to change the respective setting for the default behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.
The answer is in [Bash script with execution permissions won't run with dbl click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305650/bash-script-with-execution-permissions-wont-run-with-dbl-click?rq=1) --  which I found in Linked and Related. Thank you for UBUNTU.