# Ubuntu 18.04 how to make bash script thst execute by double-click on file?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to make shortcut that after double-click will open terminal and execute script. The problem is after make file and after d-c it open vim edit instead of execute it.
File code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/some_path/
python3 main.py
```

I try command chmod -x and chmod 755 but it don't work. In file property is set allow executing file as program.
I did try use this [How to execute a script just by double clicking like .EXE files in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows) 
but "Type dconf-editor and hit Enter." give error Command not found.
In terminal file is working, how make d-c work?

Comment: This question has been asked before: https://askubuntu.com/questions/305650/bash-script-with-execution-permissions-wont-run-with-dbl-click