# How to i open terminal through a text file

Tags: command-line, text

I cant find info about this anywhere probably its not possible to do in Ubuntu but i would like to know how for example:

I make a text file, put like `echo "Hello"` in that text file and save it on Desktop and What do i do to when i open the file in Desktop it opens the terminal and says hello?

Comment: does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-scripts) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

1. On Console(Konsole on KDE) do a cd ~/Desktop
2. nano(or your favorite editor) test ENTER
3. Write down this: 
   `#!/usr/bin/bash
   echo "Hello World"`
4. CTRL-X then y to exit and save that
5. chmod +x test(test is the name of the file)
6. on Plasma desktop(KDE) right click over the file, actions, Run in Konsole

EDIT:
After trying and searching for this I think that on moderm Ubuntu versions, at least here on my machine with Kubuntu 19.10 and ubuntu-desktop installed, this is not possible.

I searched for more info about this to try to help you and I found this:

- [Bash script with execute permissions won't run with double click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305650/bash-script-with-execute-permissions-wont-run-with-double-click)
- [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus/286651#286651)
- [How do I run a script on Linux just by double clicking it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044798/how-do-i-run-a-script-on-linux-just-by-double-clicking-it)

Please give it a try to those links, maybe some of them could work for you. For me at least they don't

Comment: im running GNOME and there is nothing saying to open in terminal